# Highcharts data value from variable array string

Tags: javascript, c#, highcharts

Got a column called ChartData in database with a string value of 4,11,25,36,50. Trying to assign this value to a hidden variable so JS can read the value of this and put this value in the data option using high charts. I have console.log the variable and looks like its appearing as a string rather than an array when being parsed across the server side to the client side.

C# code

```
string str = reader["ChartData"].ToString();

                string[] strList = str.Split(','); //seperate the hobbies by comma

                // convert it in json
                 dataStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strList, Formatting.None);

                 hiddenvariable.Value = dataStr;
```

JS code:

```
function CreateBoxPlot() {


var hv = $('#hiddenvariable').val();
alert(hv); //["40","61","65","74","77"]

var chart;
var titleText = 'Test Chart Title';
var subTitleText = 'Test Chart Subtitle';
var type = 'boxplot';
var data = hv; 

console.log(data); //["40","61","65","74","77"]

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: { type: type, inverted: true },
        title: { text: titleText },
        subtitle: { text: subTitleText },
        legend: { enabled: false },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 50
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            visible: false

        },
        yAxis: {

            visible: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Values'
            },

            plotLines: [{
                value: 80,
                color: 'red',
                width: 2

            }]

        }
    });

    chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.addSeries({ data: data });


});
```

}

However when i hardcode data to the below value this works. How do i format this correctly when its parsed over to the JS side:

```
var data = [[40,61,65,74,77]]
```

Comment: `var data = hv.map(item => parseInt(item));`

Comment: => (give me a syntax error)

Comment: Syntax error? Can you paste the error message?

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception: hv.map is not a function TypeError: hv.map is not a function
    at CreateBoxPlot (http://localhost:63705/test.js:51:19)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63705/test.js:11:5)
    at mightThrow (http://localhost:63705/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js:3534:29)
    at process (http://localhost:63705/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js:3602:12) undefined

Comment: Oooh, `var data = JSON.parse(hv);`

Comment: I can see it as an array in console log which is good. But it still does not plot my chart. It works when i hardcode this in: var data = [[40,61,65,74,77]] but not when its using my variable?

Comment: Oh so it require a double array. `var data = [JSON.parse(hv);]`, Or maybe `var data = [JSON.parse(hv).map(item => parseInt(item));]` if it need to be int as well

Comment: Nearly - seems to be putting double quotes around each number when var data = [[40,61,65,74,77]] does not have any quotes around the number?

Comment: `var data = [JSON.parse(hv).map(item => parseInt(item));]` <== Did you try this?

Comment: Yes it doesnt like the arrow... => (get syntax error)

Comment: Um I think it's not about the arrow, but more likely the semicolon. `var data = [JSON.parse(hv).map(item => parseInt(item))]` should probably work

Comment: It seems to work but it has a red squiggly line under the > of the arrow ? I googled it looks like the => wont work in IE. JavaScript critical error at line 51, column 42. Is there a way to do this same thing to work on all browsers?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Also, are you typing strictly `JavaScript` not `TypeScript`?  Which error are you getting? AVAVT is right though, the semicolon throws the problem. There are multiple different ways of writing the expression.

Comment: Using Visual Studio. Using JavaScript. I am getting a syntax error when using => but it works using chrome firefox but breaks when using IE... How else can i write the following expression so it works in all browsers:

var data = [JSON.parse(hv).map(item => parseInt(item))]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the string `'["40","61","65","74","77"]'` to js array with numbers. To make it work on each browser you can follow this approach:

1. Parse the string to js array using `JSON.parse()`
2. Loop through the created array and convert each element to number:

---

```
  var json = '["40","61","65","74","77"]',
      dataString = JSON.parse(json),
      data = [],
      i;

  for (i = 0; i < dataString.length; i++) {
    data[i] = +dataString[i];
  }
```

**Code:**

```js
$(function() {

 var json = '["40","61","65","74","77"]',
    dataString = JSON.parse(json),
    data = [],
    i;
      
  for (i = 0; i < dataString.length; i++) {
   data[i] = +dataString[i];
  }

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      inverted: true
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      crosshairs: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointWidth: 50
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      visible: false
    },
    yAxis: {
      visible: true,
      title: {
        text: 'Values'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 80,
        color: 'red',
        width: 2
      }]
    }
  });

  chart = $('#container').highcharts();
  chart.addSeries({
    data: data
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ay1xmgoc/

Answer (score -1):

Taking reference from the comments, add this to your code and then try.

```
var data = hv.map(function (element) {
  return +element;
});
```

Comment: This doesnt work. data needs to be outputted as a double array. Maybe thats whats missing but not sure?

Comment: I only gave the 2nd part ( that is to convert each element to number ) since you are facing issues using arrow functions.

You will have to parse it first before applying this function.

But this should work in all browsers.